# How can I track multiple svn branches in git

Tags: svn, git, branch

There are so many ways to skin a cat, can anyone improve on this?

Comment: If I can make a suggestion, edit the question to ask something like, "How can I track multiple svn branches using git?"  Then put your post in an answer.  Nothing wrong w/answering your own questions.  But, in its current form I'm afraid this will get down-voted and closed.

Answer (score 7):

That's a great article, but what really helped me was to understand the config for `git svn`.

Assuming your SVN is setup like:

```
$SVN_ROOT/project/trunk
$SVN_ROOT/project/branches
$SVN_ROOT/project/tags
```

your `.git/config` looks like this:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = $SVN_ROOT
    fetch = project/trunk:refs/remotes/git-svn
    branches = project/branches/*:refs/remotes/*
    tags = project/tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

then a `git branch -r` will list all the remote branches.  The "project/branches/*" says that anything on SVN in the branches dir is mapped to a remote branch.

`git checkout $branch` will check it out, but what you really want to do is `git checkout -b my_feature $branch` and work your local branch (rooted at the remote branch), and then merge in when you are done.

Comment: Hi Dave, your last paragraph; I dont fully understand, could you please elaborate further.